# PHP Regex for Paypal Payflow response

Tags: php, regex, url, paypal

I am working on Paypal Payflow for payment and right now I am having trouble extracting the Paypal response.

Paypal responses are sent in a format as given below

```
RESULT=0&RESPMSG=Approved&SECURETOKEN[25]=Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA== &SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5
```

The value inside the square braces `[]` is the length of the actual value. For example, `SECURETOKEN` is a parameter and it's value is 'Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA=='. is 25 characters long.

How can I extract each parameter and it's corresponding value from the result in PHP. I am not so good with regex and I was unable to find any solution online.

Splitting with `&` and `=` does not work in this case.

Comment: You can use [`\[(\d+)\]=[^=]+`](https://regex101.com/r/OzDWSI/1/), can you post some more examples ?

Comment: @CodeManiac This is one of the sample Paypal has provided on their website `RESULT=0&RESPMSG=Approved&SECURETOKEN[25]=Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA==
&SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5`

Comment: @CodeManiac It is not always necessary that the length field is available in the string. Moreover, how can I get an array of name- value with this regex. Thank you for your response.

Comment: The previous one will not work if your value string have `=` inside, as it matches upto `=`, let me fine tune it and come up with better one, can you please share the link from where you got the above response example

Comment: @CodeManiac https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#secure-token

Comment: @cale_b You are right. I will take the best method. I didn't see any other option when I asked for Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string looks an url, so the simple approch is use `[parse_str()][1]` it will transform the given string into an array 'well formated'.

Important the return of function will be store in the second argument (`$keys` in this example).

[Ideone - example](https://ideone.com/iqnlTc)

```
$str = 'RESULT=0&RESPMSG=Approved&SECURETOKEN[25]=Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA== &SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5';
parse_str($str, $keys);

print_r($keys);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [RESULT] => 0
    [RESPMSG] => Approved
    [SECURETOKEN] => Array
        (
            [25] => Fj 1AFUWft0 I0CUFOKh5WA== 
        )

    [SECURETOKENID] => 9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5
)
```

Comment: If there's native way, you should go with it, no need of regex +1

Comment: I like this approach except that I just lost the string which I really wanted as is. The value 'Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA==' has to be passed as is to Paypal server for processing.

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan PHP has a function for that as well, [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before sending it to PayPal.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "Do not URL encode Name-Value parameter data because it can cause problems with authentication and reporting." This statement from Paypal made me confusing.

Comment: i'm fixing the spaces into + sginal. ;)

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan Well you're not supposed to apply it to the whole query string, just the single value. Read the docs.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah, I get it. I am just worried about other encoded characters. Say for something like '%'. The + sign was just from the sample they had on their website. There is no other details given there to interpret what all characters they could be sending.

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan I really don't know what to tell you. If you know web standards better than PHP then go ahead and homebrew your own mess.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I just tested with `urlencode` and the SECURETOKEN value after encoding is `Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA%3D%3D` instead of `Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA==`.

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan Yes, and you're claiming that's an issue? You've done something wrong. You should be getting `Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA%3D%3D+`. Notice the trailing plus sign.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't have a trailing space in my input :) Moreover, isn't that an issue when we are dealing with Payment solutions? Never mind, I decided to replace spaces with + sign as suggested by rray

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan Yes you do, it's right there in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100149/870729) to parse the response into an array is the correct start.  This is how to access those values from the array:

```
$str = 'RESULT=0&RESPMSG=Approved&SECURETOKEN[25]=Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA== &SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5';
parse_str( $str, $values );
```

Now, to get the values you want:

```
$tokens = $values['SECURETOKEN'];
// results in an array: ['25' => 'Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA=='];

$token = reset( $tokens ); // results in 'Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA=='
$length = key( $tokens ); // results in '25'
```